# I am getting menu item error from flutter

Tags: arp, nt

I'm trying to make a Sidebar with Flutter, but I'm getting the error "error: 'MenuItem' isn't a function. (invocation_of_non_function at [sidebar_animation] lib\sidebar\sidebar.dart:104) " there is no problem in my code or as an import in my MENU ITEM file I also know it, but I couldn't find how to solve the error I got. Since the code output is long, I tried to explain the problem better by adding images.

MenuItem(
icon: Icons.card_giftcard,
title: "Wishlist",
),
Divider(
height: 64,
thickness: 0.5,
color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.3),
indent: 32,
endIndent: 32,
),
MenuItem(
icon: Icons.settings,
title: "Settings",
),
MenuItem(
icon: Icons.exit_to_app,
title: "Logout",

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3KZo.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XF5KN.png)

Hi guys, I'm trying to make a Sidebar with Flutter, but I'm getting the error "error: 'MenuItem' isn't a function. (invocation_of_non_function at [sidebar_animation] lib\sidebar\sidebar.dart:104) " there is no problem in my code or as an import in my MENU ITEM file I also know it, but I couldn't find how to solve the error I got. Since the code output is long, I tried to explain the problem better by adding images.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.